# How to get value in listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview

> I want to show json data in listview.The json array is shown in
>   console.but i am not able to set the adapter value in listview.It
>   always return null value.

```
     final ListView category_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_dashboard_list);
            category_detail = new Category_Dashboard_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.category_row_list, cate_list);
            category_listview.setAdapter(category_detail);

 try {
            jsono = new JSONObject(jsonvalue);
            jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("jsonvalue");
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                try
                {
                   // object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Category_Detail_Model category_obj = new Category_Detail_Model();
                    category_obj.setCategory_Title(object.getString("bookmark_title"));
                    category_obj.setCategory_Description(object.getString("bookmark_title"));
                    category_obj.setCategory_Url(object.getString("bookmark_website"));
                    category_obj.setImage(object.getString("bookmark_preview_image"));
                    cate_list.add(category_obj);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here category_listview.setAdapter(category_detail); giving null value.

Here model file is

```
public class Category_Detail_Model{

    private String category_title;
    private String category_description;
    private String category_url;
    private String category_image;

    public Category_Detail_Model() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Category_Detail_Model(String category_title, String category_description, String category_url, String category_image) {
        super();

        this.category_title = category_title;
        this.category_description = category_description;
        this.category_url =category_url;
        this.category_image = category_image;

    }


    public String getCategory_Title() {
        return category_title;
    }
    public void setCategory_Title(String category_title) {
        this.category_title = category_title;
    }


    public String getCategory_Description() {
        return category_description;
    }

    public void setCategory_Description(String category_description) {
        this.category_description = category_description;
    }


    public String getCategory_Url() {
        return category_url;
    }

    public void setCategory_Url(String category_url) {
        this.category_url = category_url;
    }



    public String getCategory_Image() {
        return category_image;
    }

    public void setImage(String category_image) {
        this.category_image = category_image;
    }

}
```

And here is Adapter class code

```
public class Category_Dashboard_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category_Detail_Model> {
    ArrayList<Category_Detail_Model> category_detail_list;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/cabin.regular.ttf");

    public Category_Dashboard_Adapter(Context context1, int resource1, ArrayList<Category_Detail_Model> objects1) {
        super(context1, resource1, objects1);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context1
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource1;
        category_detail_list = objects1;
    }

    public View getView(int position1, View convertView1, ViewGroup parent1)
    {
        // convert view = design

        View v = convertView1;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.category_imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_details_ivImage);
            holder.category_title_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_detail_title_view);
            holder.category_desc_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_detail_desc_view);
            holder.category_url_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_detail_url_view);


            holder.category_title_holder.setTypeface(font1); holder.category_title_holder.setTextSize(16.0f);
            holder.category_desc_holder.setTypeface(font1); holder.category_desc_holder.setTextSize(14.0f);
            holder.category_url_holder.setTypeface(font1); holder.category_url_holder.setTextSize(10.0f);

            // holder.txtCategory.setTypeface(font1); holder.txtCategory.setTextSize(10.0f);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        new CategoryDownloadImageTask(holder.category_imageview).execute(category_detail_list.get(position1).getCategory_Image());
        holder.category_title_holder.setText(category_detail_list.get(position1).getCategory_Title());
        holder.category_desc_holder.setText(category_detail_list.get(position1).getCategory_Description());
        holder.category_url_holder.setText(category_detail_list.get(position1).getCategory_Url());
        return v;

    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView category_imageview;
        public TextView category_title_holder;
        public TextView category_desc_holder;
        public TextView category_url_holder;

    }
}
```

Comment: dear have you create object of arraylist?

Comment: are u get the data in adapter or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bacause you set value for the adapter before load json so it give null values:

Try this:

```
final ListView category_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_dashboard_list);

 try {
            jsono = new JSONObject(jsonvalue);
            jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("jsonvalue");
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                try
                {
                   // object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Category_Detail_Model category_obj = new Category_Detail_Model();
                    category_obj.setCategory_Title(object.getString("bookmark_title"));
                    category_obj.setCategory_Description(object.getString("bookmark_title"));
                    category_obj.setCategory_Url(object.getString("bookmark_website"));
                    category_obj.setImage(object.getString("bookmark_preview_image"));
                    cate_list.add(category_obj);
                    category_detail = new Category_Dashboard_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.category_row_list, cate_list);
                    category_listview.setAdapter(category_detail);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Or maybe you forget to init your ArrayList before set json data to it. Remember to do this:

```
  ArrayList<String>  cate_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

before you set data for it.

Comment: not able to add the values in cate_list.add(category_obj); giving null pointer exception.

Comment: did you initialize it first?.. see the bottom of my answer

Comment: ArrayList<Category_Detail_Model>  cate_list; initialized in  this way

Comment: you have to write like this `ArrayList<Category_Detail_Model> cate_list = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your json and adding data to your `cate_list` after setting the adapter. Add the code for setting data to `ListView` after you parse your json:

```
try {
            jsono = new JSONObject(jsonvalue);
            jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("jsonvalue");
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                try
                {
                   // object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Category_Detail_Model category_obj = new Category_Detail_Model();
                    category_obj.setCategory_Title(object.getString("bookmark_title"));
                    category_obj.setCategory_Description(object.getString("bookmark_title"));
                    category_obj.setCategory_Url(object.getString("bookmark_website"));
                    category_obj.setImage(object.getString("bookmark_preview_image"));
                    cate_list.add(category_obj);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


 final ListView category_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_dashboard_list);
            category_detail = new Category_Dashboard_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.category_row_list, cate_list);
            category_listview.setAdapter(category_detail);
```

Comment: hey jas Whats mistakes he did??

Comment: He is adding data to `cate_list` after setting adapter. So his list has no data

Comment: yeah but i think its not give whole code of class so we cant get flow which code write in which method and all

Comment: hey jas i think he forgot to make object of arraylist